# Fastest way to decode a hexadecimal digit

Tags: algorithm, hex

I am looking for the fastest way to get the decimal value of a hexadecimal ASCII character, i.e. one that is guaranteed to appear in the following string (it can be lower or upper case, but no white space):

```
0123456789ABCDEFabcdef
```

So far, the best formula I've come up with is:

```java
char c = 'd';  // or any other hex character
int value = (((c & 0x1F) + 9) % 25;
```

Note that it is branch-free, but it does contain an expensive modulo operation.

Can I do better?

Comment: so you want d(hex)->13(int)?

Comment: I doubt it's possible without either "expensive" arithmetic or branches, since you have to map three contiguous regions of codes to one contiguous region of codes.

Comment: @MarcB Exactly. And 'A' or 'a' would yield 10, 'B' or 'b' would yield 11 and so forth and '0' gives 0, '1' gives 1, ... of course.

Comment: If you want speed, how about a simple look up table?  It's not clever, but useful.

Comment: @donjuedo I'm not so sure that lookup tables would actually be faster, since they might require memory access, which is probably much slower than a modulus... (Not sure how things compare, though, once the table is in the processor cache)

Comment: @MarkusA. I agree that it might not be faster, but the difference depends very much on your cache use around the time. What's more important here is "*have you measured it?*" and "*who'll read your code next?*"

Comment: array access is essentially `O(1)`. a few machine instructions to calculate the offset/address and retrieve the value. on a 386 cpu, a `div` (necessary for your modulo operation) is 14 cycles for an 8bit division. once you add in the cost of the bit-wise `&`, addition, a lookup table starts looking cheap

Comment: I dont know how strict you are trying to be, but I wouldn't really consider modulus an 'expensive operation' if you know you are going to be dealing with values as small as you would get from this conversion

Comment: @MarcB Asymptotic complexity aside (which is a pointless measure here, since our parameters are constant), you're grossly underestimating how complex a single memory access can be once you've enabled paging (which is practically always the case). Which is exactly why these things must always be measured.

Comment: Modulo by a constant shouldn't be *that* bad, not great (two multiplies and a bunch of cheaper ops), but not as bad as an actual modulo (ie not optimized and compiling to a division)

Comment: Might be better suited for the code review site.

Comment: I don't think this would fare very well on Code Review, until a more substantive piece of code is included for context... Also, language is not specified. I think this really is better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarcB on modern processors with cache, you can execute a whole lot of instructions in the time it takes for a single cache miss. The rules that applied in 386 days aren't always appropriate anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(d & 0xf) + ((d & 0x40) >> 3) + ((d & 0x40) >> 6)
```

Very straightforward bit fiddling.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Wfwmzj)

A slightly different variant

```
(d & 0xf) + (d >> 6) + ((d >> 6) << 3)
```

saves another bitwise `and` operation.

Both variants basically multiply the 6th bit by 9 (same as in the Mark Ransom's answer but without hardware multiplication).

Comment: Awesome! One less addition than @toth's answer. Looks like this one will be hard to beat. :)

Comment: If you put `d >> 6` into a temporary, you only need to do it once. Hopefully the compiler is smart enough to do it for you, but...

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I rely on the compiler to optimise it away. If it can't then I'll probably have much bigger performance problems down the road.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with no modulos and no branches, just a couple of shifts and subtractions.

```
int value = (c & 0x0F) + 9 - ((c&0x10)>>1) - ((c&0x10)>>4);
```

I just started from your formula, and used the fact that `c&0x10` will be `0` for letters and `0x10` for `0-9`.

Note that as is pointed out in comments, mod by a constant will optimized by compiler to multiplies and additions, but this should still be slightly better, since the compiler doesn't have the precondition that `c` is a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Sweet! That's the kind of answer I was hoping for! :) I'll give it a little more time before I accept it, in case someone else comes up with something even more clever. But this is great already! +1

Answer (score 5):

If you have a fast multiply available:

```
int value = (c & 0x0f) + 9 * (c >> 6)
```

Comment: gcc (v5.2.0, x64 target, -O3) produces exactly the same code for this line and for n.m.'s second variant. (Because it knows that it can use `leal  (%rax,%rax,8), %eax` to perform that computation.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but Daniel Lemire benchmarked [several versions](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/04/17/parsing-short-hexadecimal-strings-efficiently/) and came to the conclusion that using a simple lookup table was twice as fast as "fancy mathematical function". Copy-pasting from his article:

```
uint32_t hex_to_u32_lookup(const uint8_t *src) {
  uint32_t v1 = digittoval[src[0]];
  uint32_t v2 = digittoval[src[1]];
  uint32_t v3 = digittoval[src[2]];
  uint32_t v4 = digittoval[src[3]];
  return v1 << 12 | v2 << 8 | v3 << 4 | v4;
}
```

where `digittoval` "is a 256-byte array where 48 (or ‘0’) is mapped to 0, 65 (or ‘A’) is mapped to 10 and so forth".