# Decoding a hex string

Tags: java, python, hex, byte, decode

This is part of a bigger problem where we needed to port an old application to a new device (and of course to another programming language/framework). After a lot of effort ( sniffing the comm lines, reverse engineering the transmitted data for about a 2-3 weeks ) I managed to narrow in on what I think are the 4 bytes that contains 2 numbers. One of the number is a temperature reading like 30.51, 30.46 etc as shown in the first column (of Table 01). The other value is a float that can be in the range of something like 3.9 to 3.6 ( and even lower, with 4 decimals ). The 4 hex bytes (col 2 of Table 01) should contain both these values. I had to do some reverse engineering because no documentation is available nor the source code. I managed to narrow in on the part of java code that I think decodes the hex strings into 2 number as stated. Will someone be able to check if the code is what I think that it is? I am not a java programmer and I mostly deal with other programming languages. So I will need couple of things

1. Is the attached code responsible for decoding the hex into the 3 float numbers? This is the most important
2. If possible refactor a bit of that code so that it can run on (https://www.compilejava.net/). This is so that I can try test the algo with different sets of hex numbers.
3. "If possible" add some comments

Table 01

```
30.51 => 01:53:4e:98
30.46 => 01:53:8e:94
30.43 => 01:53:8e:91
30.39 => 01:53:8e:8e
30.39 => 01:53:4e:8e

12.36 => 01:52:88:b1
16.01 => 01:52:c9:cf
18.65 => 01:52:ca:a5
21.14 => 01:52:8b:74
```

If there is any information needed please let me know because I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out. I can record more numbers if needed.

Btw the number on the left is a temperature reading ( in celsius ). So that "may" involve a multiplication in the end to arrive at the number? I am not so sure about that but I thought I'd mention what I know about this.

I don't have the time to learn java to fix this ( it is super rare for us to deal with java ) and I have already spent close to a month on this. Really appreciate any help to just clear this hurdle. Here is the java code that decodes the hex to 2 numbers. I got this by reverse engineering the legacy app. Please note that I deleted the decompiled code that I posted earlier because I was just made aware of the fact that it is covered under an NDA.

Oops, I made a mistake of not mentioning that finally this needed to be plugged into a Python program - as I was mentioning it was part of a much bigger Python project, nearly all of which I've coded and works great. And a huge apology for not mentioning that (and forgetting to add the Python tag). I will have to rewrite this in Python.

Comment: Do you have any more rows for Table 1? Cakes near the largest and smallest relevant values would help. Also, a similar map for the first two bytes would help with those.

Comment: hi, added 4 more values to Table 01. Unfortunately I can't really get the min and max values because that would need reproduction of that environment. And also I couldn't get a map of the first 2 bytes because I can calculate that only if I know the algorithm and byte order etc. Currently for the 2nd value ( the one with 3.x something ) is shown as a symbol/progress bar. It could be some funny custom way of encoding the values ...

Comment: The code you give here isn't helpful. Method `a()` looks like it would return a temperature, yet it operates on *four* arrays of four bytes. Method `m()` operates on a single array of four bytes but it returns values around 4.16 for the example input provided. And given the creative bit mangling in that method, guessing how exactly the values are calculated is pointless. This doesn't looks like processing of raw input, rather like intentional obfuscation.

Comment: The decompiled code is kind of suspicious to me. In particular, the part I'm looking at looks like this: `for (;;) { return d3 + d1; if ((d3 < 34.1D) && (d3 >= 34.0D)) {...`. In other words, that `for` loop is completely useless, because the first statement is a `return` statement, and everything below the `return` statement is never, ever run. That actually shouldn't even compile ([see example](https://ideone.com/hygi22)). Anyway, it looks like the decompiler isn't working, *or* the code's been run through an obfuscator which was able to skip compilation checks.

Comment: The `break label406;` statements are spurious as well. Anybody trying to read this code should be doing it pretty carefully. A decent amount of it looks like garbage.

Comment: I tried couple of decompilers and I can't seem to cleanly extract the part where the 4 bytes are decoded. I am totally stuck at this point. Also I doubt if it has gone through obfuscation because quite a bit of code can be clearly read.

Comment: @Radiodef let me see if I could run this through another decompiler ... or a disassembler ( but this could make it more difficult to read? But could give a clue I guess )

Comment: Also those 4 bytes could be used in any ways ... for example I am able to convert those 4 bytes into what looks like the voltage ( 3.xxx volts ) ... pls note that those 4 bytes are carrying 2 values - voltage and temperature.

Comment: I don't know enough about decompilers to say how likely it is that one would produce wrong source code. All I can say is that this code is pretty weird and doesn't compile. I'm not old enough to know whether it would compile in a very old version of Java, but certainly the meaning of keywords like `return` hasn't changed in a way that would make the junk code in that `for(;;)` loop get executed.

Comment: @Radiodef definitely that decompiled source looks weird but my only hope is that it holds a small clue. Anything that I can build on - cos currently it is hitting a dead end. But Bob Jacobsen's answer is creating some excitement ... it's pretty close. But I need it to be accurate throughout the range. It has to have the +/- 0.05 deg c max

Comment: Are you allowed to upload the compiled code so we could download it?  This probably has to be as a full file, not pasted into an HTML window.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock, I wish I could upload but unfortunately we are not supposed to upload it. I'll check this once again - if there's a possibility I'll gladly upload the compiled code.

Comment: Could you run this javap program on your code and add the result? "javap -c YourClassNameHere.class" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock sure, I'll do that in a short while as I am out now. Also let me see if I can stream the numbers online with a visual of the actual reading. This has become a seriously interesting problem. I dun even have someone attempt to answer this on Quora too ... lol. They are a bunch of math geniuses there :) But I can confirm a zillion times over, the battery and temperature readings are hidden in those 4 bytes. I had this confirmed from someone who designs hardware for a living - and, yes - "its in those 4 bytes!" is from him.

Comment: Can't you redefine the problem and implement it from scratch (ditch the 4 byte numbers altogether and invent something new that suits your requirements)?

Comment: hi Mark, I wish I could do that :) Those bytes are coming from something on which I have little or no control on. And those bytes hold the 2 values that I am looking for. If there were a choice of implementing from scratch, I'd jump at the first oppurtunity :)

Comment: hi @ProgrammersBlock, here's the result of running that command on the class file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oN5yI-ahFsl7J-sxFLZJt-9UYydkXXA8WZWOXmkmXCY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Decompiled Code does calculate temperature:**

As you suspected, the decompiled code `class a` is capable of calculating the temperature.  The method `double a()` has the algorithm.  The decompiled code does not compile, however after a fair bit of work, it has been corrected (see below) and does calculate the temperature accurately based on your inputs and expected values.

**Results: (using mapKey=77)**

```
30.506 => 01:53:4e:98
30.460 => 01:53:8e:94
30.425 => 01:53:8e:91
30.391 => 01:53:8e:8e
30.391 => 01:53:4e:8e
12.338 => 01:52:88:b1
15.990 => 01:52:c9:cf
18.636 => 01:52:ca:a5
21.127 => 01:52:8b:74
```

**Calibration:**

Method `a()` - now called `calculateTemperature()` seems to have calibration built into it if you choose to use it.  Of the 4 arguments, the first is the hex string (of which only two octets are used by the algorithm), and the other three can *calibrate* the result.  It is hard to know how to use these values.  But if you leave them as default values as I have shown in `main()` then the resulting temperatures are calculated correctly.  Perhaps you know why you might want to calibrate the result.  One of the calibrations requires passing a value between 65 and 85 (77 is what I used).  There is another similar argument which causes multiplication of the result (zero will ignore the argument).  I found that using mapKey=77 produces results slightly too low (but 78 was slightly too high).  I found using a scale of 100175 made the results even closer to the expected values.  And the third calibration is a +/- type of calibration (zero will ignore the argument).

**Possible calculation of voltage**

After the temperature is calculated, there is some code which assigns a value of around 0.2-2.0 when the temperature is between 33.2 and 36.0.  I have called this voltage, but have no idea what it is.  For your input values, the temperature is always below 33.2, so this part of the code is effectively useless.

**Unknown Meaning of method c()**

There is a small method `c()`.  It returns a value around 4.16 - 4.18 for the values you have provided.  Does this mean anything to you?

**Working code:**

The `main()` method demonstrates how to get the temperature from a hex string, and prints the results of the input data.  The code runs on the website you mentioned in your question.  Of note is that the 3 calibration arguments do not need to be `byte[]` arrays, and may be simpler understood and used as type `int`. If you have any questions about the code, lets work in the comments (or chat) and I'll explain it to you.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Meter {

private List<Double> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();     // Used by the temperature algorithm
private Map<Integer, Double> scaleMap = new HashMap<>(21);  // Used to scale (not necessarily required)

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Meter meter = new Meter();
    meter.initData();

    //30.51 => 01:53:4e:98
    //30.46 => 01:53:8e:94
    //30.43 => 01:53:8e:91
    //30.39 => 01:53:8e:8e
    //30.39 => 01:53:4e:8e

    //12.36 => 01:52:88:b1
    //16.01 => 01:52:c9:cf
    //18.65 => 01:52:ca:a5
    //21.14 => 01:52:8b:74

    // Test each of the provided hex values

    int mapKey = 77;    // 77 seemed the best value; 78 was a bit too high

    String[] values = { "01:53:4e:98", "01:53:8e:94", "01:53:8e:91", "01:53:8e:8e",
            "01:53:4e:8e", "01:52:88:b1", "01:52:c9:cf", "01:52:ca:a5", "01:52:8b:74" };

    ByteBuffer key = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(mapKey);
    ByteBuffer scale = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(0);     // A number around 100175 perhaps provides better results
    ByteBuffer offset = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(0);    // No offset

    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        double tempC = meter.calculateTemperature(hexStringToByteArray(values[i]), key.array(), scale.array(), offset.array());
        System.out.printf("%2.3f => %s\n", tempC, values[i]);
    }

}

/**
 * Convert a hex string (which may contain the `:` character) to a byte array
 * @param hexString 4 octets of the form xx:xx:xx:xx
 * @return The byte array
 */
static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
    hexString = hexString.replaceAll(":", "");
    int len = hexString.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

/**
 * Populate the algorithm parameters (required), and the scaling factors (not necessarily required)
 */
private void initData() {

    scaleMap.put(65, 29.629);
    scaleMap.put(66, 29.660);
    scaleMap.put(67, 29.691);
    scaleMap.put(68, 29.722);
    scaleMap.put(69, 29.753);
    scaleMap.put(70, 29.784);
    scaleMap.put(71, 29.815);
    scaleMap.put(72, 29.846);
    scaleMap.put(73, 29.877);
    scaleMap.put(74, 29.908);
    scaleMap.put(75, 29.939);
    scaleMap.put(76, 29.970);
    scaleMap.put(77, 30.001);
    scaleMap.put(78, 30.032);
    scaleMap.put(79, 30.063);
    scaleMap.put(80, 30.094);
    scaleMap.put(81, 30.125);
    scaleMap.put(82, 30.156);
    scaleMap.put(83, 30.187);
    scaleMap.put(84, 30.218);
    scaleMap.put(85, 30.249);

    parameterList.add(52.94);
    parameterList.add(49.61);
    parameterList.add(46.51);
    parameterList.add(43.62);
    parameterList.add(40.94);
    parameterList.add(38.44);
    parameterList.add(36.12);
    parameterList.add(33.95);
    parameterList.add(31.93);
    parameterList.add(30.05);
    parameterList.add(28.29);
    parameterList.add(26.61);
    parameterList.add(25.05);
    parameterList.add(23.59);
    parameterList.add(22.23);
    parameterList.add(20.96);
    parameterList.add(19.76);
    parameterList.add(18.65);
    parameterList.add(17.60);
    parameterList.add(16.63);
    parameterList.add(15.71);
    parameterList.add(14.84);
    parameterList.add(14.02);
    parameterList.add(13.25);
    parameterList.add(12.53);
    parameterList.add(11.86);
    parameterList.add(11.22);
    parameterList.add(10.63);
    parameterList.add(10.07);
    parameterList.add(9.541);
    parameterList.add(9.046);
    parameterList.add(8.572);
    parameterList.add(8.126);
    parameterList.add(7.706);
    parameterList.add(7.311);
    parameterList.add(6.938);
    parameterList.add(6.588);
    parameterList.add(6.257);
    parameterList.add(5.946);
    parameterList.add(5.651);
    parameterList.add(5.374);
    parameterList.add(5.109);
    parameterList.add(4.859);
    parameterList.add(4.623);
    parameterList.add(4.400);
    parameterList.add(4.189);
    parameterList.add(3.990);
    parameterList.add(3.801);
    parameterList.add(3.623);
    parameterList.add(3.454);
    parameterList.add(3.294);
    parameterList.add(3.141);
    parameterList.add(2.996);
    parameterList.add(2.858);
    parameterList.add(2.728);
    parameterList.add(2.604);
    parameterList.add(2.487);
    parameterList.add(2.376);
    parameterList.add(2.270);
    parameterList.add(2.170);
    parameterList.add(2.075);
    parameterList.add(1.984);
    parameterList.add(1.897);
    parameterList.add(1.815);
    parameterList.add(1.737);
    parameterList.add(1.662);
    parameterList.add(1.591);
    parameterList.add(1.524);
    parameterList.add(1.459);
    parameterList.add(1.398);
    parameterList.add(1.340);
    parameterList.add(1.284);
    parameterList.add(1.231);
    parameterList.add(1.180);
    parameterList.add(1.132);
    parameterList.add(1.086);
    parameterList.add(1.042);
    parameterList.add(1.000);
    parameterList.add(0.9599);
    parameterList.add(0.9216);
    parameterList.add(0.8851);
    parameterList.add(0.8501);
    parameterList.add(0.8168);
    parameterList.add(0.7849);
    parameterList.add(0.7545);
    parameterList.add(0.7254);
    parameterList.add(0.6974);
    parameterList.add(0.6707);
    parameterList.add(0.6451);
    parameterList.add(0.6207);
    parameterList.add(0.5973);
    parameterList.add(0.5743);
    parameterList.add(0.5523);
    parameterList.add(0.5313);
    parameterList.add(0.5112);
    parameterList.add(0.4920);
    parameterList.add(0.4736);
    parameterList.add(0.4560);
    parameterList.add(0.4392);
    parameterList.add(0.4230);
    parameterList.add(0.4076);
    parameterList.add(0.3925);
    parameterList.add(0.3781);
    parameterList.add(0.3642);
    parameterList.add(0.3510);
    parameterList.add(0.3383);
    parameterList.add(0.3261);
    parameterList.add(0.3144);
    parameterList.add(0.3032);
    parameterList.add(0.2925);
    parameterList.add(0.2822);
    parameterList.add(0.2722);
    parameterList.add(0.2626);
    parameterList.add(0.2534);
    parameterList.add(0.2445);
    parameterList.add(0.2360);
    parameterList.add(0.2279);
    parameterList.add(0.2201);
    parameterList.add(0.2126);
    parameterList.add(0.2054);
    parameterList.add(0.1984);
    parameterList.add(0.1917);
    parameterList.add(0.1852);
    parameterList.add(0.1790);
    parameterList.add(0.1731);
    parameterList.add(0.1673);
    parameterList.add(0.1618);
    parameterList.add(0.1564);
    parameterList.add(0.1513);
    parameterList.add(0.1464);
    parameterList.add(0.1416);
    parameterList.add(0.1370);
    parameterList.add(0.1326);
    parameterList.add(0.1283);
    parameterList.add(0.1242);
    parameterList.add(0.1203);
    parameterList.add(0.1164);
    parameterList.add(0.1128);
    parameterList.add(0.1092);
    parameterList.add(0.1058);
    parameterList.add(0.1026);

}

/**
 * 
 * @param b1array The hex number b1:b2:b3:b4 (as a byte array)
 *            - The only bits used are b2 (6 low bits & x3f) and b3
 *            (all 8 bits & xff)
 * @param mapKey
 *            - Value from 65 to 85; if 77 then scale is 1.0; otherwise < 77
 *            or > 77 causes scaling
 * @param byte1Scale
 *            - Equal to zero (scale=1), or units in micro (10E6) where
 *            scale=value/10E6
 * @param byte1Offset
 *            - Measured in 10E6 (micro) - offset amount
 * @return The temperature in degrees Celsius
 */
public double calculateTemperature(byte[] b1array, byte[] mapKey, byte[] byte1Scale, byte[] byte1Offset) {

    double scale;
    int scaleMicroValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte1Scale).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
    if (scaleMicroValue == 0) {
        scale = 1.0D;
    } else {
        scale = scaleMicroValue / 1000000.0D;
    }

    double offsetValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte1Offset).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt() / 1000000.0D;

    /* 14 bits: b2_5 b2_4 ... b2_0 b3_7 .. b3_0 */
    byte byte2 = b1array[2];
    byte byte3 = b1array[3];
    int bitValue = (byte3 & 0xFF | (byte2 & 0x3F) << 8);
    double scaledBitValue = bitValue * scale - offsetValue;

    int key = (byte) (mapKey[0] & 0xFF);
    double mapValue = scaleMap.containsKey(key) ? scaleMap.get(key) : scaleMap.get(77);

    double param1 = 0.0;
    double param2 = parameterList.get(0);
    double result = 33.0D / scaledBitValue * (8191.0D - scaledBitValue) / mapValue;

    int i = 0;
    int j = parameterList.size();
    double minParameter = parameterList.get(j - 1);

    if (param2 < result || minParameter > result)
        return 0;

    int index = 0;
    boolean process = true;
    while (i < j && process) {
        if (result >= parameterList.get(i)) {
            if (i == 0) {
                param1 = parameterList.get(i);
                param2 = parameterList.get(i + 1);
                index = i;
                process = false;
            }
            if (process) {
                param1 = parameterList.get(i - 1);
                param2 = parameterList.get(i);
                index = i - 1;
            }
            process = false;
        }
        if (process)
            i++;
    }
    if (process) {
        index = 0;
        param2 = 0;
    }

    double voltage = 0.0;   // I don't even know if this is voltage (but it is only calculated if temp between 33.2 and 36
    double tempC = index + (result - param1) / (param2 - param1) - 40.0D;

    if ((tempC < 34.0D) && (tempC >= 33.2D)) {
        voltage = 1.95D;
    }

    while (true) {
        if ((tempC < 34.1D) && (tempC >= 34.0D)) {
            voltage = 1.881D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.2D) && (tempC >= 34.1D)) {
            voltage = 1.805D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.3D) && (tempC >= 34.2D)) {
            voltage = 1.71D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.4D) && (tempC >= 34.3D)) {
            voltage = 1.615D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.5D) && (tempC >= 34.4D)) {
            voltage = 1.52D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.6D) && (tempC >= 34.5D)) {
            voltage = 1.4249999999999998D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.7D) && (tempC >= 34.6D)) {
            voltage = 1.3299999999999998D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.8D) && (tempC >= 34.7D)) {
            voltage = 1.2349999999999999D;
        } else if ((tempC < 34.9D) && (tempC >= 34.8D)) {
            voltage = 1.14D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.0D) && (tempC >= 34.9D)) {
            voltage = 1.045D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.1D) && (tempC >= 35.0D)) {
            voltage = 0.95D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.2D) && (tempC >= 35.1D)) {
            voltage = 0.855D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.3D) && (tempC >= 35.2D)) {
            voltage = 0.76D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.4D) && (tempC >= 35.3D)) {
            voltage = 0.6649999999999999D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.5D) && (tempC >= 35.4D)) {
            voltage = 0.57D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.6D) && (tempC >= 35.5D)) {
            voltage = 0.475D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.7D) && (tempC >= 35.6D)) {
            voltage = 0.38D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.8D) && (tempC >= 35.7D)) {
            voltage = 0.285D;
        } else if ((tempC < 35.9D) && (tempC >= 35.8D)) {
            voltage = 0.19D;
        } else {
            if (tempC >= 36.0D) {
                break;
            }
            if (tempC < 35.9D) {
                break;
            }
            voltage = 0.095D;
        }
    }
    return tempC;
}

/**
 * I don't know what this function is:  It always calculates around 4.16 - 4.18
 * @param bArray The hex number b1:b2:b3:b4 (as a byte array)
 * Uses: 
 * byte0:  Low 2 bits
 * byte1:  all bits
 * byte2:  high 2 bits
 * @return I don't know the significance of this value
 */
public double m(byte[] bArray) {
    int byte2 = bArray[2];
    int byte1 = bArray[1];
    int byte0 = bArray[0];
    return 0.003077674645823156D * (((byte0 & 0x3) << 2 | (byte1 & 0xC0) >> 6) << 8
            | (byte2 & 0xC0) >> 6 | (byte1 & 0x3F) << 2);
}
}
```

**EDIT:  Method to accept a hex string as a parameter, and output temperature**

```
/**
 * Arg[0] is expected to be the input (a hex string)
 * The output is the temperature (printed to the console)
 * @param args One value; The hex string
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Meter meter = new Meter();
    meter.initData();
    int mapKey = 77;    // Scaling factor
    ByteBuffer key = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(mapKey);
    ByteBuffer scale = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(1000180);       // No scaling
    ByteBuffer offset = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(0);    // No offset

    byte[] hexString = hexStringToByteArray(args[0]);

    double tempC = meter.calculateTemperature(hexString, key.array(), scale.array(), offset.array());
    System.out.printf("%.2f", tempC);

}
```

Comment: Wow! This is among the best answer I have received. Before I digest the whole stuff, I'd like to thank you and also couple of clarification on the questions you mentioned - 1. Why the need for calibration A) In the beginning when the "decoding" didn't go well throughout the range, there was a suspect - and that suspect was whether these values are raw adc / coming for a thermocouple etc. 2) As for the method c() and values around 4.16 - 4.18, those are kinda close to the voltage values. I have not been provided the upward limit of the voltage but it is around/above 3.985 when "full"

Comment: I am turning in for the night and will gladly answer any questions you might have tomorrow

Comment: I played around with the calibration values a bit and found room to make the posted results even closer to the expected values.  Map key 77 seems the best (although 78 is close too but causes the results to be a bit high) but the results are slightly low, and by using a scale of around 100175 this increases the values marginally.   No questions? You are able to port this code to python?

Comment: Concerning `m()`: I expect this is the voltage.  If you consider the hex string (32 bits) the temperature is found in the lowest 14 bits.  Method `m()` is using the 12 bits immediately higher.  The high 6 bits are not used in the code.  The fact that `m()` uses a distinct bit range from temperature must mean it is the voltage.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing! :) And yes I will have to port it to Python. I remember during the earlier stages I could get the voltage pretty easily using all 4 bytes - an it can be achieved with pretty simple code. But I do expect some problems while porting this. I haven't had to deal with bits and bitwise operators for a while and perhaps those skills are a little rusty.

Comment: The 3.xxxx value that I get should be the voltage as it is extremely close to the range that I was given. But unfortunately then again, the upper range was never mentioned. But upper range is somewhere >= 3.985. When I monitor the reading and hook up the adapter. I can see the voltage increase and vice versa when I disconnect the adapter. So that part seems to be working fine.  And I have added how I calculate the voltage in my script (using all 4 bytes )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167473/discussion-between-m-m-and-ian-mc).

Answer (score 3):

The C, 8 and 4 values in the 4th column from left don't affect the values.  That makes me think that there are only 12 bits of information being sent for each value.  Perhaps it is the integer raw output from an ADC? If that's the case, then you can decode it with something like:

```
double valueOne(long input) {
    long x = input & 0xFFF;

    double m = (30.51 - 12.36) / (0xE98 - 0x8B1);
    int c = 0xE91;
    double b = 30.43;

    return m*(x-c)+b;
}
```

The `m*(x-c+b)` linear approximation is to make it as accurate as possible around what seems to be your operating point; you can adjust the m, c, b values as needed.

To handle the other values, create a similar routine that masks and shifts to get the right 12 bits and provide the needed m, c and b calibration values.

Here's what that computes for Table 1's values:

```
3:4e:98 30.514
3:8e:94 30.466
3:8e:91 30.430
3:4e:8e 30.393
3:4e:8e 30.393

2:88:b1 12.364
2:c9:cf 15.799
2:ca:a5 18.370
2:8b:74 20.856
```

The lowest values aren't quite right; maybe it would be better to extrapolate from a different value than the 12.36 point (see formula for the `m` value). Or maybe this is thermocouple data, which isn't quite linear.  Would need to know more about the actual circuit to comment on that.

Comment: This data has to do with a temperature sensor and it cannot be ruled out that it could be the raw output. Unfortunately there is no documentation at all on how the numbers can be derived, nor is there any documentation on the sensor itself. But the 2 values ( voltage and temperate ) are both carried by those 4 bytes. And we know that the accuracy of the bigger number ( temperature ) is ±0.05

Comment: I am not familiar with java but if you see the else part of the final "if" condition - it could hold some clues.

Comment: And the java code posted is what I got after disassembling the binary ... so unless I were an expert in java, it would be extremely difficult to point out if there are some errors/bugs that resulted from the decompilation itself.

Comment: And also the same 4 bytes holds another value, which is the voltage. The voltage should be something like 3.xxxx ( max could be 3.985 )

Comment: what temp sensor is it? I doubt it but its possible someone may have worked with that specific item before

Comment: hi @JoranBeasley, there are absolutely no markings on it... I just dissected a part of the enclosure and found this(https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fp0jYoiJxgreKugUjFvhmnRdMpPJQ_V/view?usp=sharing ). I also looked around and found what appears to be a TI CC254X ( most probably a CC2541 ) beside it.

Answer (score 2):

> I had to do some reverse engineering because no documentation is available nor the source code.

What I love about Java is that it can "easily" be decompiled.

Since you're porting something to a new device, I'm going to assume that you have the rights to go around decompiling and poking around the source code.

There are a few websites like [this one](http://www.javadecompilers.com/), which can help you a lot.

This might not directly solve the problem, but hopefully you'll be able to figure out how they encoded it :)

Comment: hi Zhang, yes - we can mess with the compiled code, as long as it is done in-house. I did try out every popular decompiler around including the one you mentioned. Thanks for the tip though :) This is getting exciting and I feel like leaving no stone unturned to solve this one but the damn time isn't on my side ... haha. And because this mostly involves decoding that bunch of hex, I even posted the question on Quora - and guess what? It's been a few days and I haven't  received any decent reply on Quora! :)

Comment: Jacobsen got real close real fast but it has to work throughout the range, because the accuracy ( of +/-0.05 ) is critical. And also the need to extract the smaller number (3.xxxx) in those 4 bytes. I am not a serious math guy and add to it this is just one of the few projects  that I am working on - so I can't go 24/7, 7 either...haiz

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna decompile the bytecode, just use a decompiler. You can use [this page](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) or use a JD plug-in in your IDE. IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse have a built-in Decompiler, just open the .class file in it and read the decompiledcode.

If you just wanna decode some hexstring, not the bytecode, use [this website](http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HexDecode)

Btw, in case you really want to build your own hex string decoder, I think using a bunch of if else statement is not a good idea. Hex encoding/decoding is just a process of moving some bits around. Using `<<` or `>>` operator will make your code pretty shorter and easier to read. May [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925589/fastest-way-to-decode-a-hexadecimal-digit) will help you.

Comment: hi, cool links. Thanks a lot. I tried a bunch of decompilers earlier on but none did a decent job. The code isn't obfuscated as far as I understand but somewhere somehow, they snap at different places when run with decompilers. Probably something to do with the framework than anything else. I'll read thru the links, it might gimme the much needed clue.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this post on Quora.

You asked for code you can run to decompile the hex in Java.  It is not clear to me where you got this code.  But I took the code above, saw that the last function converts a byte array to a double, and played with it.  You can see it doesn't work, even consistently in the wrong way, to get the temperature.
Included are handy debug functions to compare bit values.
Perhaps the other bits are needed to interact with this double in some way.

Also, are you certain that your examples are all correct?   Typically, the dividend here is similar, but some are much different.  (Run the program!)  If this code is legit, I would have expected the same dividend, at least within error.  Then all that would be needed would be to tweak the constant used to multiply the bits.

Please note these sorts of operations are the same in C++.  The primary difference is the type conversion has simpler syntax in C++ (i.e. without the ByteBuffer syntax or class libraries).  In Java a byte is simply an 8 bit signed int.  Because it IS an integer, several implicit type conversions are convenient.

This runs on https://www.compilejava.net/.
To do additional tests, just add code to the main(...) method.

Sorry, I have no idea why this pasted double space.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;



public class CrazyConvertor {



//        int t = Integer.decode("0x01");

//        System.out.println("test is "+t+"\t01");

//        t = Integer.decode("0x24");

//        System.out.println("test is "+t+"\t36");



    //30.51 => 01:53:4e:98

    //30.46 => 01:53:8e:94

    //30.43 => 01:53:8e:91

    //30.39 => 01:53:8e:8e

    //30.39 => 01:53:4e:8e



    //12.36 => 01:52:88:b1

    //16.01 => 01:52:c9:cf

    //18.65 => 01:52:ca:a5

    //21.14 => 01:52:8b:74

    public static double[] temperatures;

    public static int[] encodedBytes;

    static {

        temperatures = new double[9];

        encodedBytes = new int[9];



        encodedBytes[0] = Integer.decode("0x01534e98");

        encodedBytes[1] = Integer.decode("0x01538e94");

        encodedBytes[2] = Integer.decode("0x01538e91");

        encodedBytes[3] = Integer.decode("0x01538e8e");

        encodedBytes[4] = Integer.decode("0x01534e8e");

        encodedBytes[5] = Integer.decode("0x015288b1");

        encodedBytes[6] = Integer.decode("0x0152c9cf");

        encodedBytes[7] = Integer.decode("0x0152caa5");

        encodedBytes[8] = Integer.decode("0x01528b74");



        temperatures[0] = 30.51;

        temperatures[1] = 30.46;

        temperatures[2] = 30.43;

        temperatures[3] = 30.39;

        temperatures[4] = 30.39;

        temperatures[5] = 12.36;

        temperatures[6] = 16.01;

        temperatures[7] = 18.65;

        temperatures[8] = 21.14;

    }



    static int MASK = 0x0003ffc0;



    public static void main(String[] args)

    {





        for (int k=0; k<9; k++){

            double f = fourBytesToDouble(encodedBytes[k]);

            int x = integerElegantConversion(encodedBytes[k]);

            System.out.println("Converted double            \t"+f);

            System.out.println("Converted double elegant    \t"+fourBytesElegantConversion(encodedBytes[k]));

            System.out.println("Target value\t"+temperatures[k]);

            System.out.println("Dividend\t"+temperatures[k]/f);

            System.out.println("Dividend temp by integer\t"+temperatures[k]/x);

            System.out.println();

        }



    }



    /**

     * takes four bytes

     * function identical to m below, but easier to read

     *

     * Key programmer's note: in java, a byte is a 8-bit integer

     * So this is basically dynamic type conversion from encoded bits to a double.

     *

     * @param z  and integer representing 4 bytes

     * @return

     */



    public static double fourBytesToDouble(int z){

        //read 12 bits from middle of 3 byte array

        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(z).array();



        //grab 4 bits from first byte from bits 0 thru 1 and bits 6 thru 7 of byte 2

        int x = ((bytes[1] & 0x3) << 2 | (bytes[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);

        x = x << 8;



        //grab second byte from bits  2 thru 7 of byte 1 and bits 0 thru 1 of byte 2

        int y = (bytes[2] & 0x3F) << 2 | (bytes[3] & 0xC0) >> 6;

        int r = x | y;   //or the bytes, so you obtain 12 bits; four from byte 1 and eight from byte 2

        System.out.println("  fourBytesToDouble (int)         \t"+r);

        return 0.003077674645823156D *  new Double(r);

    }



    /**

     * original reference function

     * @param paramArrayOfByte

     * @return

     */

    public static double m(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)

    {

        int i = paramArrayOfByte[2];

        int j = paramArrayOfByte[1];

        return 0.003077674645823156D * (((paramArrayOfByte[0] & 0x3) << 2 | (paramArrayOfByte[1] & 0xC0) >> 6) << 8 | (i & 0xC0) >> 6 | (j & 0x3F) << 2);

    }



    /**

     * Same task using integer masking.

     * Probably the original code that got obfuscated by compiler

     * @param x

     * @return

     */

    public static double fourBytesElegantConversion(int x){

////        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).put(b);

////        bb.position(0);

////        int x = (bb.getInt() << 10) >> 10;

////        System.out.println("   x\t"+fourBytesBinaryString(x));

////        System.out.println("mask\t"+fourBytesBinaryString(MASK));

//        x = x & MASK;

////        System.out.println("  x1\t"+fourBytesBinaryString(x));

//        x = x >> 6;



        x = (x & MASK) >> 6;

        System.out.println("  fourBytesElegantConversion (int)\t"+x);

        return 0.003077674645823156D *  new Double(x);

    }



    public static int integerElegantConversion(int x) {

        return (x & MASK) >> 6;

    }

    /**

     * helper function to compare bits

     * @param x

     * @return

     */

    public static String fourBytesBinaryString(int x){

        String r = Integer.toBinaryString(x);

        int extra = 32 - r.length();



        for (int i=0; i < extra; i++){

            r = "0"+r;

        }

        return r;

    }



    /**

     * helper function to compare bits

     * @param b

     * @return

     */

    public static String eightBytesBinaryString(byte[] b){

        String r = oneByteBinaryString(b[0]);

        for (int k=1; k < 8; k++)  r += oneByteBinaryString(b[k]);

        return r;

    }



    /**

     * helper function to compare bits

     * @param b

     * @return

     */

    public static String fourBytesBinaryString(byte[] b){

        String r = oneByteBinaryString(b[0]);

        for (int k=1; k < 4; k++) r += oneByteBinaryString(b[k]);

        return r;

    }



    /**

     * helper function to compare bits; helper function to above

     * @param b

     * @return

     */

    private static String oneByteBinaryString(byte b) {

        String r = Integer.toBinaryString(b);



        if (b < 0){

            r = r.substring(24);

        } else {

            int extra = 8 - r.length();



            for (int i = 0; i < extra; i++) {

                r = "0" + r;

            }

        }

        return r;

    }

}
```

EDIT: typo due to copy/paste

Comment: I had a thought.   You mentioned a second voltage of say size of about 4.  Well, I need to multiply this number by a number in range of 1 to 3 to get the correct answer.  Maybe we need that number?
It is clearly not here, but I'd bet it is in a 4 byte block somewhere.

Comment: I don't know the principles behind the sensor.  Can anyone comment, would multiplying this by a voltage make any sense based on the design?

Comment: hi @BAMF4bacon, fantastic! Btw the code you saw is one that I got after running it through a decompiler because there is no source available to it. I am doing this stuff in Python but thanks for the Java code, thanks a zillion. I'll step through all that you have provided. The number (in your post few hours ago) should be in those 4 bytes too, because at the moment the screen gets updated, there is no other data being transmitted (not even a bit!) for a matter of fact - so yes it is hiding in there itself :)